# Send Shipping Address details with Stripe Custom Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a stripe checkout that's using the now unsupported "data-shipping-address="true"" parameter. This works as expected when using the simple stripe checkout with the following code:

```
<script 
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
    class="stripe-button"
    data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
    data-amount="1000" 
    data-currency="gbp" 
    data-allow-remember-me="true" 
    data-shipping-address="true" 
    data-billing-address="true" 
    data-label="Proceed to payment details" 
    data-image="" 
    data-description="TrillShirts">
</script>
```

but if I call it in a .js file I can't get it to post the data taken from the Shipping Details. Here's the code I have:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_JfqHIgPSCG2oWOsJ54PWS0Nl',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  billingAddress: 'true',
  shippingAddress: 'true',
  token: function(token) {
    console.log(token.id);
    console.log(token.email);
    // here I try to find the shippingAddress using cosole.log
    console.log(token.shippingAddressLine1);
    console.log(token.stripeShippingAddressLine1);
    // When I eventually have the shipping address, I will insert it in the same way as below
    $(".stripeToken").val(token.id);
    $(".stripeEmail").val(token.email);
    $(".stripe").submit();

    }
});

document.getElementById('pay').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:

    handler.open({
      name: 'TrillShirts',
      description: 'Childcatcher Tee',
      currency: 'gbp',
      amount: 2000
    });
  });
});
```

Both of the following return undefined in the console, so I can't figure out the format that the Shipping Details come back in.

```
    console.log(token.shippingAddressLine1);
    console.log(token.stripeShippingAddressLine1);
```

Once I know the format and have a successful console log I can use jQuery to insert the data into the form before submit.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

With Custom Checkout, when `shippingAddress` is enabled, the shipping details are passed to your `token` callback function as *second* argument of the function. This is the `args` parameter shown in the `token` callback reference [in this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#required).

So in your case you would need to modify the signature of your token callback function from `function(token) {...}` to `function(token, args) {...}` and then you should be able to get the info from `args`.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/rghpes57/3/
in this example the second `console.log` is the one you want to look at to see how the object looks like.